# How to display many images in several specific size windows, separate by tabs in php

Tags: php, jquery, emoticons

In my database query, it returns set of image names. I want to display them in a small size window (say 3x3), if there are more images (>9) it will populate to the next window by a tab or a specific symbol. People can click to that symbol to open the next window. I also want to recognize which image is chosen by user.

The idea of display is something like emoticon window in this image.

[image: http://www.askdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/iPhone-5-Emoticons-Tutorial-8.jpg]

Do you have any idea I can make it in php ?

Here is what I am trying, please feel free to correct my code:

```
<?php include "dbConnector.php" ; ?>
<table>
<tr>
<?php
require_once ("paginator.php");
$pages = new Paginator; //ew paginator object to play with and initializes the default values behind the scenes
$connector= new DbConnector();
$queryObj = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `mydb`.`images`"); 
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($queryObj);
$pages->items_total = $num_rows; //assigns total number of records to our paginator's items_total property
$pages->mid_range = 7;//number of page links to display.
$pages->paginate();//ell the paginator to get to work and paginate 

$x = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM `mydb`.`images` ORDER BY `name` DESC $pages->limit");
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($x)) 
{ 
    $i++;
    echo "<td><img src='imagefolder/".$row['name'].".png'/></td>";
    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
           echo '</tr><tr>';}

}
echo "Page $pages->current_page of $pages->num_pages";
echo $pages->display_pages();//displays our page numbers
?>
</tr>
<table>
```

The dbConnector.php as requested:

```
<?php

define("EW_CONN_PORT", 3306, TRUE);
define("EW_CONN_HOST", "localhost", TRUE);
define("EW_CONN_DB", "server", TRUE);
define("EW_CONN_USER", "root", TRUE);
define("EW_CONN_PASS", "admin", TRUE);

class DbConnector {
// Database connection
var $theQuery;
var $link;

function DbConnector(){

        // Get the main settings from the array we just loaded
        $host = 'localhost';
        $db = 'mydb';
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = '';

        // Connect to the database
        $this->link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
        mysql_select_db($db);
        register_shutdown_function(array(&$this, 'close'));

    }

  //*** Function: query, Purpose: Execute a database query ***
    function query($query) {

        $this->theQuery = $query;
        return mysql_query($query, $this->link);

    }

    //*** Function: fetchArray, Purpose: Get array of query results ***
    function fetchArray($result) {

        return mysql_fetch_array($result);

    }

    //*** Function: close, Purpose: Close the connection ***
    function close() {

        mysql_close($this->link);
    }   
}
?>
```

and paginator.php:

```
<?php

class Paginator{
    var $items_per_page;
    var $items_total;
    var $current_page;
    var $num_pages;
    var $mid_range;
    var $low;
    var $high;
    var $limit;
    var $return;
    var $default_ipp = 25;

    function Paginator()
    {
        $this->current_page = 1;
        $this->mid_range = 7;
        $this->items_per_page = (!empty($_GET['ipp'])) ? $_GET['ipp']:$this->default_ipp;
    }

    function paginate()
    {
        if($_GET['ipp'] == 'All')
        {
            $this->num_pages = ceil($this->items_total/$this->default_ipp);
            $this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;
        }
        else
        {
            if(!is_numeric($this->items_per_page) OR $this->items_per_page <= 0) $this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;
            $this->num_pages = ceil($this->items_total/$this->items_per_page);
        }
        $this->current_page = (int) $_GET['page']; // must be numeric > 0
        if($this->current_page < 1 Or !is_numeric($this->current_page)) $this->current_page = 1;
        if($this->current_page > $this->num_pages) $this->current_page = $this->num_pages;
        $prev_page = $this->current_page-1;
        $next_page = $this->current_page+1;

        if($this->num_pages > 10)
        {
            $this->return = ($this->current_page != 1 And $this->items_total >= 10) ? "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$prev_page&ipp=$this->items_per_page\">« Previous</a> ":"<span class=\"inactive\" href=\"#\">« Previous</span> ";

            $this->start_range = $this->current_page - floor($this->mid_range/2);
            $this->end_range = $this->current_page + floor($this->mid_range/2);

            if($this->start_range <= 0)
            {
                $this->end_range += abs($this->start_range)+1;
                $this->start_range = 1;
            }
            if($this->end_range > $this->num_pages)
            {
                $this->start_range -= $this->end_range-$this->num_pages;
                $this->end_range = $this->num_pages;
            }
            $this->range = range($this->start_range,$this->end_range);

            for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)
            {
                if($this->range[0] > 2 And $i == $this->range[0]) $this->return .= " ... ";
                // loop through all pages. if first, last, or in range, display
                if($i==1 Or $i==$this->num_pages Or in_array($i,$this->range))
                {
                    $this->return .= ($i == $this->current_page And $_GET['page'] != 'All') ? "<a title=\"Go to page $i of $this->num_pages\" class=\"current\" href=\"#\">$i</a> ":"<a class=\"paginate\" title=\"Go to page $i of $this->num_pages\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$i&ipp=$this->items_per_page\">$i</a> ";
                }
                if($this->range[$this->mid_range-1] < $this->num_pages-1 And $i == $this->range[$this->mid_range-1]) $this->return .= " ... ";
            }
            $this->return .= (($this->current_page != $this->num_pages And $this->items_total >= 10) And ($_GET['page'] != 'All')) ? "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$next_page&ipp=$this->items_per_page\">Next »</a>\n":"<span class=\"inactive\" href=\"#\">» Next</span>\n";
            $this->return .= ($_GET['page'] == 'All') ? "<a class=\"current\" style=\"margin-left:10px\" href=\"#\">All</a> \n":"<a class=\"paginate\" style=\"margin-left:10px\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=1&ipp=All\">All</a> \n";
        }
        else
        {
            for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)
            {
                $this->return .= ($i == $this->current_page) ? "<a class=\"current\" href=\"#\">$i</a> ":"<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$i&ipp=$this->items_per_page\">$i</a> ";
            }
            $this->return .= "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=1&ipp=All\">All</a> \n";
        }
        $this->low = ($this->current_page-1) * $this->items_per_page;
        $this->high = ($_GET['ipp'] == 'All') ? $this->items_total:($this->current_page * $this->items_per_page)-1;
        $this->limit = ($_GET['ipp'] == 'All') ? "":" LIMIT $this->low,$this->items_per_page";
    }

    function display_items_per_page()
    {
        $items = '';
        $ipp_array = array(10,25,50,100,'All');
        foreach($ipp_array as $ipp_opt)    $items .= ($ipp_opt == $this->items_per_page) ? "<option selected value=\"$ipp_opt\">$ipp_opt</option>\n":"<option value=\"$ipp_opt\">$ipp_opt</option>\n";
        return "<span class=\"paginate\">Items per page:</span><select class=\"paginate\" onchange=\"window.location='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=1&ipp='+this[this.selectedIndex].value;return false\">$items</select>\n";
    }

    function display_jump_menu()
    {
        for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)
        {
            $option .= ($i==$this->current_page) ? "<option value=\"$i\" selected>$i</option>\n":"<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>\n";
        }
        return "<span class=\"paginate\">Page:</span><select class=\"paginate\" onchange=\"window.location='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page='+this[this.selectedIndex].value+'&ipp=$this->items_per_page';return false\">$option</select>\n";
    }

    function display_pages()
    {
        return $this->return;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Sounds like pagination is the hardest part of what you are trying to do: [Pagination](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928)

Comment: Yeah, that is one element I need to know too! Thanks. I also don't know how to populate images a fix size window and recognize which one is chosen then hide the window and show the chosen image.

Comment: And the number of images each time query will be different, therefore, the number of page also different. Is it possible to make the paginate method to automatically calculate it with the fix number of items for each window?

Comment: Can you give me a piece of example code so that I can accept it as the solution ? Thanks !

Comment: Sure, put up what you have so far and I can help where I can. I gave you the pagination link, so I assume you just need help with laying out fixed widths across your page??

Comment: yes, I tried pagination link u gave, I can see the link and data but I think I did not get it totally correct. I get this notice on displaying: " Undefined index: ipp and page"
Updated my code. The display (window and data) is not yet display as I want.

Comment: all of them come up. Yes, 'images' is the table name.

Comment: Added. The exact error is: Notice: Undefined index: ipp in C:\xampp\htdocs\paginator.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined index: page in C:\xampp\htdocs\paginator.php on line 34

Notice: Undefined index: ipp in C:\xampp\htdocs\paginator.php on line 81

Notice: Undefined index: ipp in C:\xampp\htdocs\paginator.php on line 82

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a modification in regards to the pagination class to remove those errors and replaced your `DBConnector` with my `DBEngine` class.

The one element you are missing is the limiting per page and next > previous links.

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    class Paginator
        {
            var $items_per_page;
            var $items_total;
            var $current_page;
            var $num_pages;
            var $mid_range;
            var $low;
            var $high;
            var $limit;
            var $return;
            var $default_ipp = 25;

            function Paginator($_staticipp = '')
                {
                    $this->current_page     =   (!isset($_GET['page']) || (isset($_GET['page']) && !is_numeric($_GET['page'])))? 1:$_GET['page'];
                    $this->mid_range        =   7;
                    $_GET['ipp']            =   (!empty($_staticipp) && is_numeric($_staticipp))? $_staticipp: $_GET['ipp'];
                    $this->items_per_page   =   (!empty($_GET['ipp']) && is_numeric($_GET['ipp'])) ? $_GET['ipp']:$this->default_ipp;
                }

            function paginate()
                {           
                    if(isset($_GET['ipp']) && $_GET['ipp'] == 'All') {
                            $this->num_pages        =   ceil($this->items_total/$this->default_ipp);
                            $this->items_per_page   =   $this->default_ipp;
                        }
                    else {
                            if(!is_numeric($this->items_per_page) || $this->items_per_page <= 0)
                                $this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;

                            $this->num_pages = ceil($this->items_total / $this->items_per_page);
                        }

                    $this->current_page =   (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))? (int) $_GET['page']:0; // must be numeric > 0
                    if($this->current_page < 1 Or !is_numeric($this->current_page)) $this->current_page = 1;
                    if($this->current_page > $this->num_pages) $this->current_page = $this->num_pages;
                    $prev_page          =   $this->current_page-1;
                    $next_page          =   $this->current_page+1;

                    if($this->num_pages > 10) {
                            $this->return = ($this->current_page != 1 And $this->items_total >= 10) ? "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$prev_page&ipp=$this->items_per_page\">« Previous</a> ":"<span class=\"inactive\" href=\"#\">« Previous</span> ";

                            $this->start_range = $this->current_page - floor($this->mid_range/2);
                            $this->end_range = $this->current_page + floor($this->mid_range/2);

                            if($this->start_range <= 0) {
                                    $this->end_range += abs($this->start_range)+1;
                                    $this->start_range = 1;
                                }

                            if($this->end_range > $this->num_pages) {
                                    $this->start_range -= $this->end_range-$this->num_pages;
                                    $this->end_range = $this->num_pages;
                                }

                            $this->range = range($this->start_range,$this->end_range);

                            for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++) {
                                    if($this->range[0] > 2 And $i == $this->range[0]) $this->return .= " ... ";
                                    // loop through all pages. if first, last, or in range, display
                                    if($i == 1 Or $i == $this->num_pages Or in_array($i,$this->range)) {
                                            $this->return .= ($i == $this->current_page And $_GET['page'] != 'All') ? "<a title=\"Go to page $i of $this->num_pages\" class=\"current\" href=\"#\">$i</a> ":"<a class=\"paginate\" title=\"Go to page $i of $this->num_pages\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$i&ipp=$this->items_per_page\">$i</a> ";
                                        }

                                    if($this->range[$this->mid_range-1] < $this->num_pages-1 And $i == $this->range[$this->mid_range-1]) $this->return .= " ... ";
                                }

                            $this->return .= (($this->current_page != $this->num_pages And $this->items_total >= 10) And ($_GET['page'] != 'All')) ? "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$next_page&ipp=$this->items_per_page\">Next »</a>\n":"<span class=\"inactive\" href=\"#\">» Next</span>\n";
                            $this->return .= ($_GET['page'] == 'All') ? "<a class=\"current\" style=\"margin-left:10px\" href=\"#\">All</a> \n":"<a class=\"paginate\" style=\"margin-left:10px\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=1&ipp=All\">All</a> \n";
                        }
                    else {
                            for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++) {
                                    $this->return .= ($i == $this->current_page) ? "<a class=\"current\" href=\"#\">$i</a> ":"<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$i&ipp=$this->items_per_page\">$i</a> ";
                                }

                            $this->return .= "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=1&ipp=All\">All</a> \n";
                        }

                    $this->low = ($this->current_page-1) * $this->items_per_page;
                    $this->high = (isset($_GET['ipp']) && $_GET['ipp'] == 'All') ? $this->items_total:($this->current_page * $this->items_per_page)-1;
                    $this->limit = (isset($_GET['ipp']) && $_GET['ipp'] == 'All') ? "":" LIMIT ".$this->low.",".$this->items_per_page;
                }

            function display_items_per_page()
                {
                    $items = '';
                    $ipp_array = array("",9,'All');
                    foreach($ipp_array as $ipp_opt)    $items .= ($ipp_opt == $this->items_per_page) ? "<option selected value=\"$ipp_opt\">$ipp_opt</option>\n":"<option value=\"$ipp_opt\">$ipp_opt</option>\n";
                    return "<span class=\"paginate\">Items per page:</span><select class=\"paginate\" onchange=\"window.location='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=1&ipp='+this[this.selectedIndex].value;return false\">$items</select>\n";
                }

            function display_jump_menu()
                {
                    for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++) {
                            $option .= ($i==$this->current_page) ? "<option value=\"$i\" selected>$i</option>\n":"<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>\n";
                        }

                    return "<span class=\"paginate\">Page:</span><select class=\"paginate\" onchange=\"window.location='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page='+this[this.selectedIndex].value+'&ipp=$this->items_per_page';return false\">$option</select>\n";
                }

            function display_pages()
                {
                    return $this->return;
                }
        }

    class DBEngine
        {
            protected   $con;
            // Create a default database element
            public  function __construct($host = '',$db = '',$user = '',$pass = '')
                {
                    try {
                            $this->con  =   new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));
                        }
                    catch (Exception $e) {
                          return 0;
                        }
                }

            // Simple fetch and return method
            public  function Fetch($_sql)
                {
                    $query  =   $this->con->prepare($_sql);
                    $query->execute();

                    if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
                            while($array = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                    $rows[]   =   $array;
                                }
                        }

                    return (isset($rows) && $rows !== 0 && !empty($rows))? $rows: 0;
                }

            // Simple write to db method
            public  function Write($_sql)
                {
                    $query  =   $this->con->prepare($_sql);
                    $query->execute();
                }
        } ?>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <?php
            $con                =   new DBEngine("host","database","user","pass");
            $pages              =   new Paginator(9);
            $queryObj           =   $con->Fetch("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mydb.images"); 
            $num_rows           =   $queryObj[0]['COUNT(*)'];

            $pages->items_total = $num_rows; //assigns total number of records to our paginator's items_total property
            $pages->mid_range   = 7;//number of page links to display.
            $pages->paginate();//tell the paginator to get to work and paginate  ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><?php echo $pages->display_items_per_page(); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <?php
            $_sql               =   "SELECT * FROM mydb.images ORDER BY `name` DESC ".$pages->limit;
            $x                  =   $con->Fetch($_sql);
            $i                  =   1;
            foreach($x as $val => $row) { ?>
                    <td style="border:1px solid;"><img src="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" style="max-width: 40px;" /></td>
                    <?php
                    if ($i % 3 == 0) { ?>
                </tr>
                <tr><?php
                        }
                        $i++;
                } ?>

            Page <?php echo $pages->current_page; ?> of <?php echo $pages->num_pages; ?>
            <?php echo $pages->display_pages();//displays our page numbers ?>
        </tr>
    <table>
```

Comment: I have some difficulty using your DBEngine instead of my dbConnector. When I replace my db name inside I still get some errors, so Im trying to use my dbconnector with your code

Comment: Ok, now I can get it to run without the notice about ipp and page mentioned above. But it shows all the image on one page, and there are 3 columns but many rows. Actually I want a window of 3x3. And the next 9 images will be on next windows and so on ...

Comment: Do you get it limit to show only 9 images per page ? I got all my 12 images in one page and it shows "page 0 of 0 All" in the page link buttons. Another thing is I also get warning "Table 'mydb.mydb.images' doesn't exist in C:\xampp\htdocs\..." when I add my info into your code, not sure why.

Comment: This is what mine looks like: [tester](http://www.xolifestyleworldwide.com/client_assets/workboard.php?page=1&ipp=9)

Comment: Yes, it works !! Is it possible to make the default number of item per page (Do not let user to choose). And I don't know the page link show like this "Page 1 of 2 12All" (I have totally 12 images, looks like it show there also). Is this possible to make it show  <<1,2>> (with previous and next buttons) instead of the above? u have very nice piece of code !

Comment: Ok, just to show 3 x 3, you (I already made the edits above so you'll need to copy two spots) just modify the `Paginator()` class to accept a default static number of results and then at the bottom when declaring this class, you add the desired static number (9 in this case - 3x3=9) `$pages = new Paginator(9);`. Now, to get the HTML you want, you need to go edit the `paginate()` class to how you want it. Remove the jump menu, etc...I think the rest of it you can figure out. The pagination is the hard part.